# How to use $_POST correctly -- can't get button to work with POST

Tags: php, html, post, input

The question I have is how to get these input buttons to work.  I need them to call and perform the appropriate function when the button is clicked, however, that does not work.  Here is the code so far.  I don't think I am using $_POST correctly.

```
<form method="POST" action = "class.ElementalStone.php">
    Select your magic...
    <input type="submit" name="potion" id="potion" value="" class="potion">
    <input type="submit" name="redMagic" id="redMagic" value="Red Magic"  class="magic.red">
    <input type="submit" name="blueMagic" id="blueMagic" value="Blue Magic" class="magic.blue">
    <input type="submit" name="yellowMagic" id="yellowMagic" value="Yellow Magic" class="magic.yellow">
</form>

    <?php
        if ( !isset($_SESSION['stone']) ):
            $_SESSION['stone'] = new ElementalStone;
        else:
            $_SESSION['stone']->displayStone();
        endif;

        for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++){
            if($i == 1 || $i == 2 || $i == 4):
                if(isset($_POST["potion"])):
                    //$potion = $_POST['potion'];
                    usePotion();
                else if(isset($_POST["redMagic"])):
                    //$redMagic = $_POST['redMagic'];
                    $_SESSION['stone']->useMagic("red");
                else if(isset($_POST["blueMagic"])):
                    //$blueMagic = $_POST["blueMagic"];
                    $_SESSION['stone']->useMagic("blue");
                else if(isset($_POST["yellowMagic"])):
                    //$yellowMagic = $_POST["yellowMagic"];
                    $_SESSION['stone']->useMagic("yellow");
                endif;
            else:
                $_SESSION['stone']->randomAction();
            endif;
        }

    ?>
```

Here is the full code for the HTML file:

```
<?php
    require 'class.ElementalStone.php';

    session_start();

    //unset($_SESSION['stone']);
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon-normal.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon-normal.ico" type="image/x-icon">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />

        <title>Elemental Stones | Normal</title>
    </head>

    <body class="clearfix">
        <div>
        <form method="POST" action = "class.ElementalStone.php">
            Select your magic...
            <input type="submit" name="potion" id="potion" value="" class="potion">
            <input type="submit" name="redMagic" id="redMagic" value="Red Magic" class="magic.red">
            <input type="submit" name="blueMagic" id="blueMagic" value="Blue Magic" class="magic.blue">
            <input type="submit" name="yellowMagic" id="yellowMagic" value="Yellow Magic" class="magic.yellow">
           </form>


        <?php
            if ( !isset($_SESSION['stone']) ):
                $_SESSION['stone'] = new ElementalStone;
            else:
                $_SESSION['stone']->displayStone();
            endif;

            for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++){
                if($i == 1 || $i == 2 || $i == 4):
                    if(isset($_POST["potion"])):
                        //$potion = $_POST['potion'];
                        $_SESSION['stone']->usePotion();
                    elseif(isset($_POST["redMagic"])):
                        //$redMagic = $_POST['redMagic'];
                        $_SESSION['stone']->useMagic("red");
                    elseif(isset($_POST["blueMagic"])):
                        //$blueMagic = $_POST["blueMagic"];
                        $_SESSION['stone']->useMagic("blue");
                    elseif(isset($_POST["yellowMagic"])):
                        //$yellowMagic = $_POST["yellowMagic"];
                        $_SESSION['stone']->useMagic("yellow");
                    endif;
                else:
                    $_SESSION['stone']->randomAction();
                endif;
            }

        ?>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the class.ElementalStones.php:

```
<?php
    class ElementalStone {
        public $size;
        public $color = array("","");
        public $valid_colors = array("red", "blue", "yellow");  
        public $actions;

        public function __construct() {     
            $size = rand(1,4);

            $this->setSize($size);
            $this->setColor();
            $this->actions = 5;
            $this->displayStone();      
        }

        public function getSize() {
            return $this->size; 
        }
        public function setSize($new_size = 1) {
            if ($new_size > 4):
                $this->size = 1;
            else:
                $this->size = $new_size;    
            endif;
        }

        public function getColor() {
            $color = implode(" ", $this->color);
            return $color;  
        }
        public function setColor($new_color = "") {
            array_push($this->color, $new_color);

            if (count($this->color) > 2):
                array_shift($this->color);
            endif;

        }

        public function displayStone() {
            echo '<p class="stone-'.$this->getSize().' '.$this->getColor().'">'.$this->actions.'</p>';  
        }

        public function displayAction($action) {
            switch ($action):
                case "No more":
                    echo '<p>'.$this->getScore().'</p>';
                    break;

                case "red":
                case "yellow":
                case "blue":
                    echo '<p class = "magic '.$action.'"></p>';
                    break;

                case "potion":
                    echo '<p class="potion"></p>';
                    break;

                default:
                    echo '<p class = "unknown">X</p>';
                    break;
            endswitch;  

            $this->actions--;
        }

        public function useMagic($type) {
            if ($this->actions == 0):
                $this->displayAction('No more');
                return;
            endif;

            if (in_array($type, $this->valid_colors)):
                $this->displayAction($type);

                $this->setColor($type);
                $this->displayStone();
            else:
                $this->displayAction();

                $this->setColor();
                $this->displayStone();              
            endif;  
        }

        public function usePotion() {
            if ($this->actions == 0):
                $this->displayAction('No more');
                return;
            endif;

            $new_size = $this->getSize() + 1;

            $this->displayAction("potion");

            $this->setSize($new_size);

            $this->displayStone();  
        }

        public function randomAction() {

            $die = rand(0,3);

            switch ($die):
                case 3:
                    $this->usePotion();
                    break;
                default:
                    $this->useMagic($this->valid_colors[$die]);
                    break;
            endswitch;
        }

        public function getScore() {
            sort($this->color);

            switch ($this->color):
                case(array("blue", "red") == $this->color):
                    $score = 600;
                    break;
                case(array("blue", "yellow") == $this->color):
                    $score = 500;
                    break;
                case(array("red", "yellow") == $this->color):
                    $score = 400;
                    break;
                case(in_array("blue",$this->color)):
                    $score = 300;
                    break;
                case(in_array("yellow", $this->color)):
                    $score = 200;
                    break;
                case(in_array("red",$this->color)):
                    $score = 100;
                    break;
                default:
                    $score = 50;
                    break;
            endswitch;      

            $score *= $this->size;

            return $score;
```

}
    }

Comment: Evidently missing [`session_start();`](http://www.php.net/session_start)

Comment: Are those these code blocks in the same file? If so, your action should be directed to the file with the PHP code.

Comment: What indicates that something goes wrong? Nothing is posted? Or your session doesn't persist?

Comment: By the way I am very new to PHP.  But I do have the `session_start();` at the beginning.@Fred -ii-  These code blocks are in the same file, and the action is directed at that separate file with the PHP functions. @Arian

Comment: Well if it is, then add it in your question. That's the FIRST thing that gets asked when something is either not mentioned, nor included in a question/code. @user3369140 --- It just raises a brow higher than the other ;-)

Comment: @showdev I am not sure what is happening.  When I click on the buttons, the screen just goes white.

Comment: Where is the `ElementalStone` class that you're using or are you using it in `->useMagic` etc.? Plus this function `usePotion()` no other reference to it. Is what you've posted full code? @user3369140

Comment: So the separate php file is class.ElementalStone.php which contains `useMagic()`

Comment: When you use `class="magic.red"` inside an HTML form, this refers to a **CSS** class and not a PHP class. @user3369140 --- But I guess you knew that.

Comment: @Fred-ii-I apologize for not being clear. In addition to the file I posted, I have a CSS file that I am referring to for my button class, and then a separate file for my PHP class that is use in the action for my form, and that I call the methods from.  I think.  Again, this is all fairly new to me, so I sometimes struggle to explain the problem.

Comment: @user3369140 If your screen just goes white, you have a fatal error in your code. Can you check the error-logfiles?

Comment: @cyper So for some reason it isn't generating an error-log file.  It only generated the error log when there was an error with initial page load, before clicking any buttons. So frustrating!

Comment: @user3369140 My problem is: I see no mistake in your usage of $_POST. You can test it [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/QLmYxS).

Comment: @cyper oh I see, so, any idea on what the actual problem is?  The program is supposed to generate a stone, and then either apply magic, or use a potion on it depending on the click.  It will do this 5 times.  The 3rd and 5th stone actions are to be randomly generated.  Hopefully you can understand a little better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone note me if I'm wrong, but what I read from the comments, the HTML and PHP code is in the same file. If this is happening, you need to separate the files and send the data to a separate file with the second code block. For example:

index.html:

```
<form method="POST" action = "handlep.php">
Select your magic...
<input type="submit" name="potion" id="potion" value="" class="potion">
<input type="submit" name="redMagic" id="redMagic" value="Red Magic"  class="magic.red">
<input type="submit" name="blueMagic" id="blueMagic" value="Blue Magic" class="magic.blue">
<input type="submit" name="yellowMagic" id="yellowMagic" value="Yellow Magic" class="magic.yellow">
```

handlep.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require("class.ElementalStone.php");
    if ( !isset($_SESSION['stone']) ):
        $_SESSION['stone'] = new ElementalStone;
    else:
        $_SESSION['stone']->displayStone();
    endif;

    for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++){
        if($i == 1 || $i == 2 || $i == 4):
            if(isset($_POST["potion"])):
                //$potion = $_POST['potion'];
                usePotion();
            else if(isset($_POST["redMagic"])):
                //$redMagic = $_POST['redMagic'];
                $_SESSION['stone']->useMagic("red");
            else if(isset($_POST["blueMagic"])):
                //$blueMagic = $_POST["blueMagic"];
                $_SESSION['stone']->useMagic("blue");
            else if(isset($_POST["yellowMagic"])):
                //$yellowMagic = $_POST["yellowMagic"];
                $_SESSION['stone']->useMagic("yellow");
            endif;
        else:
            $_SESSION['stone']->randomAction();
        endif;
    }

?>
```

Additionally, the error you were throwing on initial page load was from you trying to use the ElementalStone class without first requiring it.

Comment: I just added the rest of the code for the program, except for the stylesheet.  Hopefully that can be more helpful.

Comment: You must separate the files. PHP is run and is only run when you initially run the page. So even when you submit the form, you are submitting it to the class file, which does not know what to do with the post information. The only other option would be to self-post the form, which would be making the form's action the page that the form was on. Based on your layout of the page, that would work. For example:`<form method="post">` would do the trick. Leaving out the action defaults the action to the current page. @user3369140